# Gnuplot C++ plotting in real time from txt files

Tags: c++, gnuplot, continuous

Hi I am currently plotting data from a file through a pipe in c++. I have written a function that reads in the text file, processes the information, plots the data in the text file and plots labels and arrows as needed.

Now I need a way to plot smoothly in a loop, so that a different text file is read and plotted every iteration without the Gnuplot window flickering.

For example:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    Processing_Plotting(i, gp);
}
```

This is the code i have in the main program which will plot the text file indicated by 'i'. eg: laserData1, laserData2 etc..

Currently the plot flickers and is unreadable due to the speed that it is called. 
I have looked for a way to plot data in real time with Gnuplot but haven't had much luck,
any help would be appreciated. Thanks

A picture of the sort of thing I am plotting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQGM.jpg

Comment: Are you sure gnuplot is made for this? I think it might be designed for a static plot file..

Comment: I came across this -- http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html -- some time ago, never tried it but it might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of an animation that comes with the [gnuplot-iostream](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) library.  It doesn't flicker, at least not on my machine (Linux).  Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library, so that is a shameless plug.

Your code snippet doesn't show how you actually interface with gnuplot, however there are three things you must be sure to do: 1) don't close and then reopen the pipe after each frame, 2) call `fflush` on the pipe after every frame, and 3) add a delay between frames.  To delay on Linux call `::usleep(microseconds)` (and include `unistd.h`), on Windows call `::Sleep(milliseconds)` and include `windows.h`.

The thing about piping animation data to gnuplot is that you don't know if it is keeping up.  So the flush and the sleep are vital.  But I have built an oscilloscope out of gnuplot so I know it can work well.

Comment: Hi thanks, im using pipes to send to gnuplot. After reviewing my code, it seems to be working much better. it flickers slightly but its much more viewable than before. Probably just need to tweak the Sleep values. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, this API doesn't support 3d plots.

Comment: It does support 3d plots.  There are such examples included with the package.